# How to Export a rendered image to RAW single channel

Tags: export, image

I am trying to create a height map that I can import in Supreme Commander Editor. Other software like softdesk and photoshop seem to manage this but I can't figure out how to do it with Blender.

According to other tutorials it needs to be RAW, Single channel, 16 bits, IBM PC format.

Here are options recommended for photoshop according to Supreme Commander community wiki.

[image: Photoshop raw options]

Another tutorial that uses Autodesk Softimage show the following settings.

[image: Autodesk Softimage settings]

I tried emulating these settings by saving the rendered image I had as TIFF, BW, 16 bit Color Depth and trying out the several compression options. Nothing seems to work however.

Just to get an idea of the file format I dropped my exports in a hex editor and compared them to a height map export of Supreme Commander and it seems all my attempts have some sort of header (I'm guessing) about 8 bytes long. Compared to the empty height map I can export from the Supreme Commander Editor I don't see a header.